# Exchange 2010 - attempting to add a mailbox db copy returns a DCOM error in event viewer

Tags: exchange-2010

When I attempt to add a mailbox database copy to another mailbox server, it returns "Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."  The event viewer on the source server logs an event ID 10009, DistributedCOM:  DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer [Server] using any of the configured protocols.  I've rebooted both mailbox servers, no change.  I have 8 other replicated mailbox databases between these two servers that can fail over to each other without issues.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response - it was indeed a firewall issue.  I'm using CheckPoint UTM1 security appliances and running VPN between sites.  After I re-installed policy, the issue cleared up.

Comment: It turns out that the Smart Defense feature on the CheckPoint firewalls was rejecting some of the DCE-RPC packets coming through the VPN even though the configuration was set to allow all traffic through VPN connections.  They do have a hotfix for this issue - see CheckPoint's article sk42402 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any local software firewalls running? I would disable them between the two, and try again. If successful, you know the answer.

https://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2009/11/28/dcom-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer.aspx